# Is it normal to have inconsistent values of accuracy when running a classification algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, algorithms

I ran several algorithms on several datasets (i.e. SVM, KNN, Decision Tree, Naive Bayes, Logistic Regression and MLP).

Due to it some randomization process in creating the training sets, the accuracy produced from each algorithm is not the same.

I did not train each algorithm using the whole training set, however, I randomly chose a specific number of training samples. Thus, in each run of the same algorithm, different training sets were created.

Is this normal?

If it is normal, how I’m going to report the results if I run it today is different from yesterday?

Another problem, if I have recorded the previous results and then changed some experimental setup, the results have also changed which made my recording for the previous results are useless.

Answer (score 3):

Accuracy is a statistic, and like any other statistic, it is subject to random variation. You've described a source of the random variation in your Question: you're changing how the training and testing data are composed.

One way to report accuracy in these circumstances is to train many models and report the average accuracy and standard errors.

Comment: I did that. But, still, average accuracy is not the same I run another round of multiple runs

Comment: @Aqee Why would it be? An average is also a statistic. If I draw 10 numbers from a nontrivial distribution, for example a uniform [0,1] distribution, the average will is likely to be different than the average of a different batch of 10 numbers drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: So, the average should be the same even with another round of run?

Comment: No, the averages are unlikely to be the same. Randomization of train/test folds provides different data to the model; having different data *probably* has a different average.

Answer (score 1):

What you could, and probably should, do is to fix random seeds when spiting the data to train and test sets, to make sure that each algorithm uses exactly the same train and test set if you want to compare their performance. Otherwise, this may be comparing apples to oranges, since some algorithms may by chance just get the "lucky" test samples, consisting of easier examples, or less influential bad ones.

Comment: Ah-ha! Sounds promising! Thanks!